# Is it possible to publish local db online with azure?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, database, azure, cleardb

I've very recently started doing ASP.NET web development, and i have a student azure subscription, and i want to know if its possible to publish a project online with azure (which i am already doing) but so that it would also publish the local database i have on my PC with it, so it would actually allow registering online?

I also got some Clear db thing off the azure market, because my subscription wont allow me to have the default database on azure, and i cant get it to connect.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Fixed link.

YES.
Here is documentation from Microsoft of how to publish a project and the local DB instance to Azure.
Scroll down half way to get to the Database publishing.
[Microsoft Contoso Example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/publish-to-azure)

Comment: THis is the error i get, which makes no sense because i have access to all of the source files:Web deployment task failed. (Failed to create type 'Microsot.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices'.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXCEPTION_WHILE_CREATING_OBJECT.)

Comment: Here is a link to someone with the same type of error.  Thier problem was in thier connection string to thier LocalExpress instance.  What kind of localdb are you using?  http://forums.asp.net/t/1865225.aspx?Publish+Web+Cannot+Create+Object+Error